# Добавление элемента в одномерный динамический массив

Tags: массивы, c++

Предположим в задаю массив так:

```
int *p,q; ///q мне предварительно известно
p=new int q;
```

так вот, как мне увеличить при необходимости кол-во элементов в массиве?

Comment: а может использовать `std::vector<int>`?
А если нужно уметь изменять и работать с указателями, то realloc.

Comment: @KoVadim, realloc уместен только при выделении через malloc/calloc.

Comment: а я не утверждал, что с new он будет работать. А при правильной готовке realloc можно только им память и выделять.

Comment: И удалять тоже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не хотите использовать родной для C++ STL `vector<int>`, то вместо `new/delete` можно использовать абсолютно POSIX-овские `malloc/realloc/free` из libc.

Собственно, можно обойтись и одним `realloc(ptr, size)`, умело управляя значениями `ptr` и `size`.

См. `man 3 realloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Только создав новый динамический массив и скопировав туда старый.

В реальных проектах в таких случаях, чтобы на выделять память каждый раз, выделяют ее с запасом.